# Zendesk: How to get count of tickets under each priority related to a specific view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

So in my rails app, I am trying to use an api to retrieve the count of all tickets related to specific view. But I want the count related to each priority. An example scenario: There are 25 tickets in View A. 19 of them are normal priority and 4 of them are high priority. I want to make an api request and get 19(for normal) in one of the request and 4(for high) in the other request. 
I trying to come up with an api url based on the documentation, but I am going nowhere. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific endpoint for the count of tickets in a view based on priority, but you can return all of the tickets in a view, and then sort them by priority on your own.

I recommend using the official [Zendesk API gem](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_rb) for this. Once you've [initialized the client](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_rb#configuration), you could use this to return the counts for high and normal priority tickets in a view (replace `VIEW_ID` in the code below):

```
view = client.views.find(id: VIEW_ID)
urgent_count = view.tickets.select {|x| x.priority == "urgent"}.count
high_count = view.tickets.select {|x| x.priority == "high"}.count
```